# I have some 3d Assets in .bob file format. Is there any way to open them?

Tags: 3d, blender, maya, raytracing, glblendfunc

I have some 3d Assets in .bob file format. Is there any way to open them ?

These .bob file format comes with texture maps and .bin files

Comment: I guess the first question is: where do they come from? Eg. which app produced them?

Comment: It appears to depend on your operating system [XnView](https://conversionai.com/file/image/bob-bob-bitmap-image/blend-blender-3-d-data-file), appears to be the tool to look for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.